# Create multiple files from one csv column. Python 2.7.12

Tags: python-2.7

I need to create separate files base on a column.

I'm getting data from source #1.
Then sending the data to source #2, but source #2 only recognizes the code for column 2.
I can take the data and replace the code.

testdata.csv

```
1|b|430418886
1|f|434324988
1|c|445454512
1|f|430418574
1|a|432343445
1|d|437657654
1|e|424328828
1|a|430236546
1|e|434565445
1|c|430418988
1|d|430420012
1|b|476556568
```

codelist.csv

```
a|171
b|172
c|173
d|174
e|176
f|177
```

I can create the full list, but I'm unable to separate the files based on the code.
The group of files would look like this.

```
171.csv
1|171|432343445
1|171|430236546

172.csv
1|172|430418886
1|172|476556568

173.csv
1|173|445454512
1|173|430418988

174.csv
1|174|437657654
1|174|430420012

176.csv
1|176|424328828
1|176|434565445

177.csv
1|177|434324988
1|177|430418574
```

Here my code, so far, to create the full list.

```
def get_site_code_dict(site_code_file):
    mydict = dict()
    with open(site_code_file) as inputs:
        for line in inputs:
            name, code = line.strip().split("|")
            mydict[name] = code
    return mydict

def process_raw(raw_file, site_code_dict):
    with open(raw_file) as inputs, open('ouput.csv', 'w') as outlist:
        for line in inputs:
            active, code, idnumber = line.strip().split("|")
            outlist.write("1"+'|')
            outlist.write(site_code_dict[code]+'|')
            outlist.write(idnumber+'\n')
    outlist.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    site_code_dict = get_site_code_dict("codelist.csv")
    process_raw("testdata.csv", site_code_dict)
```

Output:

```
1|172|430418886
1|177|434324988
1|173|445454512
1|177|430418574
1|171|432343445
1|174|437657654
1|176|424328828
1|171|430236546
1|176|434565445
1|173|430418988
1|174|430420012
1|172|476556568
```

I was thinking about creating a second script that would take this final list, then separating it.
But all in one would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common pattern that can be solved with a dictionary and two for loops.  This pattern can be used when grouping elements together by a common attribute, in this case the `code`

The idea behind the code is to:

1) Create a dictionary that can group everything by code

2) Loop through all records and add information to the dictionary

3) Loop through all the keys of the final dictionary and output the information per code

```
def get_site_code_dict(site_code_file):
    mydict = dict()
    with open(site_code_file) as inputs:
        for line in inputs:
            name, code = line.strip().split("|")
            mydict[name] = code
    return mydict

def process_raw(raw_file, site_code_dict):
    code_to_instances = {} # set up out empty mapping/dictionary
    with open(raw_file) as inputs:
        for line in inputs:
            active, letter, idnumber = line.strip().split("|")
            code = site_code_dict[letter]
            if code not in code_to_instances: # if the code hasn't yet been added to the dict
                code_to_instances[code] = [] # Create an entry with a blank list of instances
            code_to_instances[code].append({ 'active': active, 'id': idnumber }) # Add the element to the list

    for code in code_to_instances.keys(): # for each code
        with open(code + '.csv', 'w') as outlist: # open a file with a named based on the code
            for instance in code_to_instances[code]: # for each instance
                outlist.write(instance['active'] +'|') # write the instance information per line
                outlist.write(code +'|')
                outlist.write(instance['id'] +'\n')     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    site_code_dict = get_site_code_dict("codelist.csv")
    process_raw("testdata.csv", site_code_dict)
```

Comment: That's it...!!! I would have never got to that, creating a "empty mapping/dictionary". And I think I understand it, going through it. Double thumbs up for you!!!